# Cuando preciono mi TextInput se cierra mi aplicación de React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Tengo mi aplicación de react native que se la pase a otra persona para que la probara, ahora, cuando llega al apartado donde tiene un TextInput para escribir un comentario, preciona el TextInput para escribir, la aplicación se cierra sola, no muestra nada.

Ahora en cuanto a codigo para mi componente tengo lo siguiente:

```
<Animated.View
    style={[{ position: 'relative' }]}
    layout={Layout.easing(Easing.bounce).easing(Easing.bezier(5, 5, 2, 5))}
    entering={ZoomInEasyUp}
    exiting={ZoomOutEasyUp}
    >
    <TextInput value={comment} onChangeText={setComment} multiline mode="outlined" label="Comentario" style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }} />
</Animated.View>
```

Tambien, estoy usando React Native paper, para crear el TextInput.

En mi dispositivo no presenta ningun fallo, es al momento de compilarlo y pasarlo a otro dispositivo, en el que surgio el problema fue un motorola.

Entonces, no se si es por el dispositivo o es react native paper

expo: 48.0.21
react-native: 0.71.14
react-native-paper:5.8.0